# How can Guice annotated injections be converted to Spring dependency injection

Tags: spring, guice

I set up this binding with Guice

```
bindConstant().annotatedWith( SecurityCookie.class ).to("JSESSIONID");
```

I need to migrate to Spring.
What would be the equivalent code with Spring ?

Answer (score 2):

Use [FieldRetrievingFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/FieldRetrievingFactoryBean.html).